# Detect parent class variable or property is changed by other child class in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have parent UIViewController A which has some properties. And I have child UIViewController B,C,D which are inheriting from A.

My question is:
In the B, I change Parent properties value. How can C,D know Parent value is changed from B?

Basically I want to share properties between children.

Thanks in advance.

Code example;

```
@interface A : UIViewController{
NSString *string1; //This is just example
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string2;
@end
```

Child B

```
@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
//here I change string1 and string2;
@end
```

Child C

```
@interface C : A
@end

@implementation C
//here I want to get changed string1 and string2 by Child A;
@end
```

Child D

```
@interface D : A
@end

@implementation D
//here I want to get changed string1 and string2 by Child A;
@end
```

At the moment, I am using **Singleton** to store all the value and It is working well, but I think **there should be better way** in such situation?

Comment: Parent/child in terms of class hierarchy or view hierarchy?

Comment: KVO or pattern observer. You can google it for both. Depending of how you are handling the dependency, and when you need to bind them.

Comment: `Singleton` and `NSNotification` would be a good solution. When you change singleton values send a notification to C and D, and run/call a method in C and D.

Comment: to me seems a very confusing design or question. if A is a singleton, B,C, D inherit from it? so B,C and D objectes will hold a different instance of A. can you be more specific about your class hierarchy

Comment: I updated question, hope it clear

Comment: You can't even see changes to ViewControllerA in another instance of ViewControllerA.  It's all about addressability.

Comment: @HotLicks Have you even heard about KVO? That is the way to do such things! I don't understand why this question got down vote......

Comment: @brianLikeApple - How can you do KVO without the address of the "observee"?

Comment: @HotLicks I gave a mark to htafoya. That is the best way to do it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the simplest thing that you can do is have the property that is inherited, but override the getter and setter in the parent view so that it read/write to a static variable.

```
@interface A : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sharedString;
@end

@implementation A

static NSString* _sSharedString;

- (NSString*) sharedString {
   return _sSharedString;
}

- (void) setSharedString: (NSString*) aString {
   _sSharedString = aString;
}

@end
```

You may wish to synchronize the property.

This, thinking out of the code, will change the value for all children. I understood that that was what you needed (only value sharing), but if you also need a notification when the value changes you could add some method that notifies children (instances) whenever value changes.

Comment: Have you tried it before? I just use this way, but not working.

Comment: @brianLikeApple yes I just made an example and it works well. In fact property can be **assign**, but it still works. How are you implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the parent class send a message when its properties change.  Subclasses could implement a method for that message, and in it do whatever they have to do to adapt to the change.

I seem to remember something like this already being built in to Cocoa though...

Ahh.  Here it is.  Look into [Key-Value Observation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  Cocoa will automatically send messages when a property changes, as long as the properties are KVC compliant.  You just have to implement a method in the child to handle them, and subscribe to the change events.

So in your child class, you'd say something like

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"thePropertyName"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:nil];
```

and have a method like

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)observee
                        change:(NSDictionary*)change
                       context:(void*)context
{
    // here's where the magic happens
}
```

`keyPath` will be the name of the property that changed, and `change` will contain the new value under a certain key with a constant name (the name's `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`, no quotes).  (You can generally just look up the new property as well.)

If there will be a lot of properties to watch, this might get cumbersome for each child to subscribe to each property's changes.  How you'd handle that depends on how exactly everything's related, but eh.  Having to care so much about the parent is kind of a smell in itself...

Comment: KVO sounds great. I will give you mark if there is no better way.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I guess htafoya's answer is better way? Do you think so? That's why I gave mark to him.

Comment: @brianLikeApple: Depends on what you need, but i don't really like the idea of static properties that look like instance properties.